# Media Queries to select different 960 gs

Tags: css, import, media-queries

I am using the following code below to select different css files depending on the size of the window of my browser. However the first one doesn't seem to work when I resize the window to that size, even if I refresh the page. I am not sure what I should be doing to fix this. Thanks.

```
@import url("css/960.css") screen and (max-device-width: 1200px);
@import url("css/2520.css") screen and (max-device-width: 2560px);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taking a guess here but I don't think it will work because you are using `max-device-width` and not `max-width`.

`device-width` is the virtual pixels a device is capable of displaying.

> [Device-width (Mozilla)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/Media_queries#device-width) - 
>       Describes the width of the output device (meaning the entire screen or page,
>       rather than just the rendering area, such as the document window).

I don't think you can fake that with changing the size of a browser window.

`max-width` on the other hand is a measurement of the actual viewport displayed in the browser.

> [Width (Mozilla)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/Media_queries#width) - The width media feature describes the width of
>   the rendering surface of the output device (such as the width of the
>   document window, or the width of the page box on a printer).

So your options are either try using max-width:

```
@import url("css/960.css") screen and (max-width: 1200px);
@import url("css/2520.css") screen and (max-width: 2560px);
```

or try using some kind of device simulator like an iPad simulator or an actual device to test that your media queries are working properly.

Comment: Thanks for the help, the second one seems to be working but not the first media query, but that is the same as before. I will try on a iPad as soon as I put it online. I don't see why this wouldn't work though.

Comment: I'm assuming the first one won't work because the max-device-width of your screen is much bigger than 1200px.  Hence the suggestion to use width instead as that relies on the browser window size rather than the size of the screen.

Comment: Did you change both imports and not just the 960 import line?

Comment: so I opened it up in google chrome and it worked, then I thought maybe I need to clear my history or clear the cache, I did that and now it works in safari too. Thanks so much.

Comment: Ahh, the old browser cache strikes again! No probs, glad I could help.